# Is Correct to Use CSS3 VW & VH in 2016 for responsive and CrossBrowse sites

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was wandering  if in 2016 is the correct time and place to use css3 vw & vh units for creating responsive sites, from my experience this is the easiest way to make it happen... but i have not seen almost nowhere using this technic. Why is that so? And if you have better way doing responsive sites pleas share...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VH and VW are relative to the height / width of the viewport, so they are ideal for scaling elements based on the viewport size.

For example if you want a 2 column layout, specifying the width of each column as being 50vw will work well.  According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) browser support is good if you don't need to use vmax.

<s>Scaling is one aspect of responsive design, another is changing the page layout.</s>
As correctly noted by [George Chanturia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4174693/george-chanturia) below, the following comments refer to adaptive design, not responsive design.

Say you wanted your 2 column layout to collapse to a single column on smartphones you'll probably want to use media queries and pixels or rems or ems

eg

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 25em) { 
...
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
...
}
```

For sure you could use VM and VW  inside those media queries but it's not a feature you can test for in the actual media query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea, everything you said above  is  correct and i agree except of that the responsive design aspect is of changing the page layout, this is clearly the aspect of adaptive design :-)

Comment: thank you for pointing this out @GeorgeChanturia, you are 100% correct, I should have been accurate in my terminology ;)